# onClick not working inside of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

for some reason the onclick listener is not responding to click events in the following fragment, any ideas why?

```
public class TestFragment  extends Fragment{

    private TextView textViewOne;
    private RadioButton radioButtonOne;
    private RadioButton radioButtonTwo;
    private RadioButton radioButtonThree;
    private Spinner spinnerOne;
    private RadioGroup radioGroupOne;
            String buttonSelected;
            Activity activity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        activity = getActivity();


        View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tank_layout7, container, false);

         textViewOne = (TextView) result.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         ratioButtonOne = (RadioButton) result.findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
         ratioButtonTwo = (RadioButton) result.findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
         ratioButtonThree = (RadioButton) result.findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
         spinnerOne = (Spinner) result.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
         radioGroupOne = (RadioGroup) result.findViewById(R.id.radio_group1);

        radioGroupOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                int checkedRadioButton = radioGroupOne.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                switch(checkedRadioButton){
                 case R.id.radioButton1:
                     buttonSelected = "button one selected";

                  break;
                 case R.id.radioButton2:
                     buttonSelected = "button two selected";

                 break;      
                 case R.id.radioButton3:
                     buttonSelected = "button three selected";

                 break;
                 default:

                }
                Toast.makeText(activity, "radio button selected " + buttonSelected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            });

        return(result);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an `OnCheckedChangeListener` on the `RadioGroup`, not an `OnClickListener`:

```
radioGroupOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        switch(checkedId){
            // Your code    
        }   
    }
});
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html